# Machine in domain is not accepting domain credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

I have added a Windows Server 2008 (virtual machine) into a domain.

1. The newly added machine properties shows the system name as systemname.domainname
2. The AD is listing the newly added machine name under Domain computers lists.

Issue: But when I tried to login with the domain credentials (domainname\username and password), it is not allowed.
When I tried to login with local credentials (username and password), it is allowed. Looks like it still accepts the local credentials only not the domain credentials.

Event Log is not showing any error specific to domain user login failures.

Few more observations:
On the newly added machine, I checked the users and groups. It shows Administrator but not Administrator/Domain Users. When I tried to add this entry, it says Administrator is already part of Domain users and the entry I added got deleted automatically.

Any idea what I should check to enable the domain credentials? Is there any configuration fault in building this VM?

(I added two other servers and I could work on that with domain credentials)

Comment: What's the error when logging on? Have you tried to disjoin and rejoin the domain?

Comment: no error while logging in. Login username and password window is shown again and again. And, yes i removed the machine from domain and rejoined it, rebooted. nothing helped.

Comment: You're POSITIVE there's no errors - even ones that disappear quickly? My first thought would be an issue loading the profile. Have you checked the event log?

Comment: What error is shown in the event logs, then?  I'm honestly a little tempted to close this question, because there isn't enough information to really diagnose the problem.  Help us help you - add more information to your question.

Comment: `But when i tried to login with the domain credentials, it is not allowed. when i tried to login with usual workgroup credentials, it is allowed` - There is no such thing as `workgroup credentials`. There are domain credentials and local machine credentials. Do you mean that you can login with a local user account but can't login with a domain user account? When trying to login with a domain user account are you prepending the domain name in the username field (domain\user)? When you say it's not allowed, what do you mean exactly? give us the exact wording of the message you get.